# How to split text between multiple characters in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, split

I have a log file with the following information:

```
RTSP0 rtsp://admin:******@192.168.0.104:554/onvif1
```

where, 'admin' is the username, '******' is the password, '192.168.0.104' is the camera IP and '554' is the camera port. I want to extract these values separately and store these values in different variables, which will later be parsed to the GUI.

Since there are multiple characters in the line, I'm not sure how I can split them.
Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Hi, you could give an acknowledge to the answers by upvoting them, at least to give something back for their effort. You're not obliged to do so, but it would be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation points to upvote an answer. :/

Comment: Now you should... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about regex?

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r".*//(?P<username>\S+):(?P<password>.*)@(?P<ip_address>.*):(?P<port>.*)/")

data = "RTSP0 rtsp://admin:******@192.168.0.104:554/onvif1"

for match in regex.finditer(data):
    username = match.group('username')
    password = match.group('password')
    ip_address = match.group('ip_address')
    port = match.group('port')

    print(
        "Username: {0}\nPassword: {1}\nIP Address: {2}\nPort: {3}"
        "".format(username, password, ip_address, port)
    )
```

The result is:

```
Username: admin
Password: ******
IP Address: 192.168.0.104
Port: 554
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you! I want to avoid using extra packages like [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html), and this is tge most optimum solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html):

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> o = urlparse('rtsp://admin:******@192.168.0.104:554/onvif1')
>>> o
ParseResult(scheme='rtsp', netloc='admin:******@192.168.0.104:554', path='/onvif1', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> o.username
'admin'
>>> o.password
'******'
>>> o.hostname
'192.168.0.104'
>>> o.port
554
```